# How do I use randomTrips.py or other tools to generate pedestrians which travel same distance

Tags: python, sumo

I am working on using SUMO and traci to simulate the trajectory of pedestrians. Now I need generate pedestrains which walk the same distance from same origin but reach different destination. How can I get those pedestrians meet the requiements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give custom edge weights to randomTrips.py. In your case the easiest way is probably to create a file say `weights.src.xml` with the following content:

```
<edge id="mysrc" value="1"/>
```

This will give `mysrc` probability 1 for being chosen as src and all other edges 0. Then you can use the following call:

```
$SUMO_HOME/tools/randomTrips.py -n net.net.xml --weights-prefix weights --min-distance 1000 --max-distance 1500 --persontrips --validate
```

Please be aware that the distance is beeline distance and not walking distance. Depending on your network this may or may not be a good approximation.